# Closed subspaces and weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $B$ be a Banach space, and $E$ a closed subspace of $B$.

I have a sequence $x_n \in E$ and some $x \in E$. Is it true that 
$x_n \to x$ in the weak topology of $E$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ in the weak topology of $B$?

To me this seems obvious, I just want to make sure I don't make a basis mistake:

**Proof**

$\Rightarrow$ Let $f \in B'$ be a functional. Then the restriction $f|_E \in E'$ and hence 
$$
f(x_n)=f|_E(x_n) \to f|_E(x) = f(x) 
$$

$\Leftarrow$ Let $f \in E'$. Then By Hahn-Banach we can extend this to $g \in B'$ and then we have
$$f(x_n)=g(x_n) \to g(x) =f(x) $$

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

**P.S.** If this is correct, does anyone have a reference for this?

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that $\sigma(E,E') = \sigma(B,B')\lvert_E$, the subspace topology induced on $E$ by the weak topology on $B$ is the weak topology of $E$. Proof: Hahn-Banach. Note that it plays no role that $B$ is a Banach space and $E$ closed, this holds for all Hausdorff locally convex $B$ and all subspaces $E$ of $B$, closed or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer This is exactly why I was puzzled, I needed this result to simplify a proof in a paper I am working on; it is a trivial consequence of Hahn-Banach, yet I couldn't find it in any basic introduction to FA. Since the restriction of the weak topology to subspace is the weak topology on the subspace seems a simple yet important property of the weak topology I started doubting myself :)...

Comment: From the samples I know, most basic introductions unfortunately don't look at the topological side at all. If you look at the families of seminorms inducing the respective weak topologies, it's immediate from Hahn-Banach, that may be why it's (almost?) never mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perfect, thank you very much. I was pretty sure that this is the case. As I said when a basic result like this with a straighforward proof is not mentioned is typically for one of two reasons: either is too trivial or the proof contains a gap. I was pretty sure it is the first reason, but I would rather err on the caution side :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Moreover I don't see a more straightforward way to prove the equivalence. Great job!